# Telerik RadButton change text colour on tab/focus/active

Tags: html, css, button, webforms, telerik

I have an issue with a web project in which I am using Rad-buttons with a white background and black text. When the user navigates the page using the tab key and tabs on to the rad button, the text is highlighted in white and therefore causes the text to disappear into the white background.

I have attempted to change the forecolor text on "active" status of the radbutton, which is the CSS class used when the button is tabbed on to, but I am seemingly unable to change it.

This is the code that I have been have looking at,

```
.RadButton_Metro.RadButton:active {
border: 0px solid #F47B20 !important;
}

.RadButton_Metro.RadButton:focus{
border: 0px solid #F47B20 !important;
}
.RadButton_Metro.RadButton:focus
{
border: 0px solid #F47B20 !important;
}

.RadButton_Metro.RadButton:focus .rbDecorated
{
border: 0px solid #fff !important;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The HTML for the Rad button is as follows:

```
 <%--Add New Button--%>
<telerik:LayoutColumn>
 <telerik:RadButton runat="server" 
   ID="addButton" 
   Text="<%$ Resources:Controls, addNewButton %>"
   OnClientClicked="addNew" 
   AutoPostBack="false" 
   Skin="Metro"
   CssClass="button" 
   Icon-PrimaryIconCssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
   EnableViewState="false">
  </telerik:RadButton>
 </telerik:LayoutColumn>
```

Comment: Please post your html part too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

```
.RadButton_Metro.RadButton:focus .rbDecorated
{
    border: 0px solid #fff !important;
    color:black !important;
}
```